# JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter modification not visible in @Injected HttpServletRequest

Tags: jax-rs, cdi

I have a JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter that looks for an Azure AD authentication token and if present, should integrate with the system and replace the token with our own JWT. The strange thing, however is that modifictions to the header values are not visible further on in the execution chain when my service CDI interceptors looks at the headers from an @Inject HttpServletRequest.

Fresh WildFly application server

Comment: How are you setting the headers? `requestContext.getHeaders().put(key, value)`? Probably the JAX-RS context objects do not affect the underlying servlet objects - the `HttpServletRequest`. If you use a servlet filter you *can* replace the `HttpServletRequest` - maybe it is more suitable for your case.

Comment: It really looks like the servlet/jax-rs artifact go their own parallel route or something.

I tried using a servlet filter and wrapping the request for the chain in a  but it didn't hit  the \@Inject:ed artifact. I'll probably just make a simple \@RequestScoped container and populate it in the filter. Shouldn't be any less secure since the request object is used as the backing storage anyways.